# How to write mail where the topic inside mail is not our concern

Tags: business-writing, email, letter

Today I received a mail from our support team which is beyond our concern and we can't look into the matter.
I need to mail them back "As we can not do anything regarding this case". Since this will not be appropriate way to mail them, what else i can use in my mail to reply them back politely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"FYI - This issue is not related to our department/team. Please refer to --- --- for a better solution."**

**"Our team is not in the best position to handle this issue. Refer a more oriented team for quicker resolution"**